# Scikit-Learn like models for production?

Tags: scikit-learn, raspberry-pi, pmml, onnxruntime

I've currently fit a model using [sktime](https://www.sktime.org/en/latest/) (a scikit like library) which provides interfaces to dump and load pickled models. However if I fit in ***x86*** (64 bit OS) and run inference on raspberry pi zero which is ***armv6*** (32 bit OS) the predictions are completely different on the same test set. Digging deeper into the issue I found we have to export in either PMML or ONNX format and then inference using that for cross-architecture operations. The problem is PMML is limited and doesn't support sktime functions and ONNX Runtime Inference is currently broken for raspberry pi zero w (armv6). What are my options?

Comment: How did you install sktime on raspberry pi? Could you please try to answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76659428/how-to-install-sktime-on-raspberry-pi