# How to install sktime on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, numpy, raspberry-pi, numba, sktime

I want to use sktime for time-series classification inference on a Raspberry Pi. I am not able to install it properly with the required dependencies, especially of numpy and numba. When I run `pip install sktime` it installs correctly and also import properly. But when I try to use `fit` or `predict` it throws an error.

```
pip install sktime

# In python interpreter
import numpy as np
from sktime.classification.kernel_based import RocketClassifier
rocket = RocketClassifier(num_kernels=2000)
X_train = np.array([[[1,2,3,4,4,5]], [[1,2,3,4,5,5]], [[1,2,4,5,6,7]]])
y_train = np.array([0, 0, 1])
rocket.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

This gives.

```
UnsupportedParforsError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython mode backend)
The 'parallel' target is not currently supported on 32 bit hardware.
During: lowering "id=0[LoopNest(index_variable = parfor_index.62, range = (0, X_size0.1, 1)), LoopNest(index_variable = parfor_index.63, range = (0, $50binary_multiply.23, 1))]{335: <ir.Block at /home/sashi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sktime/transformations/panel/rocket/_rocket_numba.py (180)>}Var($parfor_index_tuple_var.69, _rocket_numba.py:180)" at /home/sashi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sktime/transformations/panel/rocket/_rocket_numba.py (180)
```

I believe it because the `numpy` and `numba` versions are incompatible.

```
numba             0.52.0
numpy             1.21.1
```

I tried `pip install numba==0.53.0` but install fails with `Failed to build llvmlite`.

My platform is:

```
- Current OS
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:    11
Codename:   bullseye
11.7
- Kernel
6.1.21-v7+
- Architecture
armv7l
- Model
Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
```

How to install sktime on raspberry pi?

Any help if greatly appreciated!

Comment: The problem looks to be related with 32 vs 64 bit architecture. Which one are you running on ypur raspberry? If you are running 32 bit can you install the 64 bit os instead?

Comment: I am running a 32 bit OS. I shall try installing the 64 bit OS and try.

Comment: @MatteoZanoni Thanks! Your suggestion worked. I changed the OS to 64bit and the code ran without an error. Please add your suggestion as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error it appears that the sktime model `roket_numba` only works on 64 bit architercture.

You are running a 32 bit version of Raspbian and that is the problem.